# how to read input from xmega then showing it on hyperterminal

Tags: c, avr

I'm trying to read an input from my ATxMega128a1 then show it on my hyperterminal. 8bit input (4 low, 4 high, lsb & msb). got a push button installed on port pin 6.

I already wrote code, but when I compile it, I get this error:

> "expected ')' before '*' token"

Here is my code:

```
   #define x PORTH
   PORTE.DIRCLR     =    PIN6_bm;
   PORTE.PIN6CTRL   =    PORT_OPC_PULLDOWN_gc;

while(1)
{
    char x;

    if(!(PORTH_IN&PIN6_bm)) 
    {               
        // if button pressed
        PORTJ_OUTSET = PIN0_bm;
        PORTJ_OUTSET = PIN1_bm;
        PORTJ_OUTSET = PIN2_bm;
        PORTJ_OUTSET = PIN3_bm;
        PORTJ_OUTCLR = PIN4_bm;
        PORTJ_OUTCLR = PIN5_bm;
        PORTJ_OUTCLR = PIN6_bm;
        PORTJ_OUTCLR = PIN7_bm;

        scanf("%d",&x);
        printf("%d\n",x);           
    }                                                                   
}

return 0;
}
```

What did I do wrong?
And, am I doing it right for my purpose?

Comment: On which line did you get this error ?

Comment: Just remove the `#define x PORTH`.

This doesn't make any sense, because then each time you write `x` in your program the `x`will be replaced by `PORTH` by the preprocessor.

Then the compiler actually sees `char PORTH;` instead of `char x;` and this conflicts with the previous declaration of `PORTH` (which you didn't show btw.).

Comment: Don't `#define` single letter macros for the whole file. Use longer and self-explanatory names. This also applies to variables, but for macros it can cause much more chaos.

Comment: The last `}` in your code mismatched. Also your code is outside any function. That can cause confusing error messages (alternatively you are showing us partial code with *relevant* parts missing, but I'm sure you wouldn't do that to us...).

Answer (score 0):

PORTH is defined by `#define PORTH (*(unsigned char *) 0x102)`.

As Michael Walz points out in his comment, you end up with a problem of defining x as one thing and then declaring it as a variable.

```
char x; // becomes
char PORTH; //which becomes
char (*(unsigned char *) 0x102);
```

which doesn't work because a declaration needs a variable name in it.
Perhaps, you didn't need to use x in two different ways.

But perhaps, the main objection to your approach is using `scanf()`. To read PORTH, just assign it into a variable, or even just print it directly.

```
char c = PORTH; // copies the value of the inputs pins into variable c.
printf("%d\n", PORTH); // prints the value of the input pins as a number.
```

It's pretty hard to tell what you are trying to do without more code, but I hope you can get it working.

Comment: you're right sir.. i already correct it. thx so much sir for the clue..